# Trying to Express A Factorial As A Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factorial

I'd like to express the following as a polynomial.
$$(a-1)(a-2)(a-3) . . . (a-b)$$
where $b<a$

I'm currently working on it now, but wanted to see if anyone's already done it, or already know what the answer is.

Comment: That is *already* a polynomial :-)

Comment: Expended form : $\sum_{i=1}^b a^i (-1)^{b-i} (\sum_{I \subseteq[1,b], |I|=b-i+1} \prod_{k \in I} k) $. Do you need something clearer?

Comment: This is often called the "falling factorial" and often written as $(a-1)_b$. The coefficients are messy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Answer (score 1):

Here are some asymptotic results of mine
that might be of some use
(although the product
goes in the wrong direction):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{(x+(n-1)/2)^n-x(x+1)...(x+n-1)}{(x+(n-1)/2)^{n-2}(n^3-n)/24}
=1
$$

and

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
(x+(n-1)/2)\dfrac{(x+(n-1)/2)-(x(x+1)...(x+n-1))^{1/n}}
{(n^2-1)/24}
=1
$$

An outline of the proofs is here:

[Limit of $\sqrt[n]{(x+1)...(x+n)} - x$ as $x \to +\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036441/limit-of-sqrtnx1-xn-x-as-x-to-infty/1037687#1037687)